# Can a class implementing an interface include fields that are missing from the parent interface?

Tags: typescript

Working with the code below. I want to enforce the constraint that all classes implementing `InterfaceParent` have a function called `add` that accepts an `InterfaceParent` (or an implementing class) and return an `InterfaceParent` (or an implementing class). However, since `InterfaceChild` has a new field, `randomVariable` that is missing from the interface it implements, I get the following error:

```
    Property 'add' in type 'InterfaceChild' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'InterfaceParent'.
  Type '(n: InterfaceChild) => InterfaceChild' is not assignable to type '(n: InterfaceParent) => InterfaceParent'.
    Types of parameters 'n' and 'n' are incompatible.
      Property 'randomVariable' is missing in type 'InterfaceParent' but required in type 'InterfaceChild'.ts(2416)
InterfaceParentChild.ts(6, 3): 'randomVariable' is declared here.
```

What's going on here? The code I'm working on:

```
interface InterfaceParent {
  add: (n: InterfaceParent) => InterfaceParent
}

class InterfaceChild implements InterfaceParent {
  randomVariable: number = 1

  add = (n: InterfaceChild): InterfaceChild => new InterfaceChild()
}

export default InterfaceChild
```

Comment: Why does `InterfaceChild`'s `add()` method specify that `n` is another `InterfaceChild` if it doesn't do anything with `n` at all?  Why not `(n: InterfaceParent): InterfaceChild => new InterfaceChild()`?  If you have a use case that requires the kind of (unsound) class implementation you're doing, maybe you can show it?

Comment: I mean, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMRgbW) is the problem that happens if you try to extend function parameters covariantly.  If you don't understand covariance and contravariance, read [this article](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).   There are ways to make this compile, like [method syntax](https://tsplay.dev/w6B4Rw) or [polymorphic `this`](https://tsplay.dev/WPjkLN) but they either sidestep or turn a blind eye to the problem, they don't really solve it.  I guess your actual use case would be useful to know before suggesting a solution.

Comment: Could you explain how this is unsound? This was just the smallest possible example that reproduced the error. Say, for example, there was a constructor that set the value of `randomVariable`, and in the call to the constructor, I passed in `this.randomVariable + n.randomVariable`.

Comment: Paul Wheeler's answer explains it and so does the linked article about covariance and contravariance.  If you claim to be an `InterfaceParent` then you are claiming that your `add` method will accept any `InterfaceParent` that the caller wants to give you.  You can't stipulate that you will only accept `InterfaceChild` inputs without violating the contract for `InterfaceParent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message spells it out pretty clearly:

Type `(n: InterfaceChild) => InterfaceChild` is not assignable to type `(n: InterfaceParent) => InterfaceParent`.
Types of parameters 'n' and 'n' are incompatible.

Your class `InterfaceChild` doesn't correctly implement `InterfaceParent` because the `add` function **must** accept any `InterfaceChild` as it's argument. You cannot make your type constrains **more strict** on *inputs* in a class that implements an interface.

However, you can be more strict regarding the output type of the function, so the return type of `InterfaceChild` is fine because all `InterfaceChild` types will implement `InterfaceParent`.

```js
interface InterfaceParent {
  add: (n: InterfaceParent) => InterfaceParent
}

class InterfaceChild implements InterfaceParent {
  randomVariable: number = 1

  add = (n: InterfaceParent): InterfaceChild => new InterfaceChild()
}

export default InterfaceChild
```

Comment: [This article](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) that jcalz linked to helped me understand this better. From what I'm understanding, telling my implementing class that I want to use a more specific type doesn't actually enforce this, as the types defined in the interface take precedence. So if I tell my implementer that I only want it to take an `InterfaceChild`, it will only enforce the `InterfaceParent` constraint from the interface, so I could also pass in `InterfaceChild2`. Generics seem the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Paul's excellent answer, you can use Generics to tell TypeScript which class your method will use in parameter:

```
interface InterfaceParent<T extends InterfaceParent<any>> {
  add: (n: T) => T
}

class InterfaceChild implements InterfaceParent<InterfaceChild> {
  randomVariable: number = 1

   add = (n: InterfaceChild) => new InterfaceChild() 
}
```

Here, I declare a generic `T` which extends `InterfaceParent`, and during the implementation, I declare that your function will use `InterfaceChild`.